# Chatbot, when is HIPAA required

Tags: chatbot, hipaa

We will build a chat bot for a medical device in combination with an App.

Chatbot job is to help for question about the device, app and general questions about the siknes where the device is build for.

Needs the Chatbot to be a hipaa compliance service or not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow does not offer legal and/or regulatory compliance advice.